# String encoding difference in NodeJS and .Net

Tags: node.js, arrays, .net, string, encoding

The short story is I need to port a .NET application to NodeJs and I'm stuck.
This is some kind of password hashing algorithm so I really need a code that returns the same output in NodeJs.

```js
const password = 'Asdfgh@';
const saltByteArray = Buffer.from([250, 106, 6, 180, 111, 229, 165, 162, 186, 86, 137, 89, 153, 76, 94, 105, 241, 1, 50, 174, 65, 119, 212, 250, 152, 244, 166, 24, 195, 245, 235, 9]);
const saltStr = Buffer.from(saltByteArray).toString();
const str = saltStr + password;
const pwdByteArr = Buffer.from(str, 'utf8');

// The result of the above should be the same as this, but it's not:
const pwdByteArray = Buffer.from([239, 191, 189, 106, 6, 239, 191, 189, 111, 229, 165, 162, 239, 191, 189, 86, 239, 191, 189, 89, 239, 191, 189, 76, 94, 105, 239, 191, 189, 1, 50, 239, 191, 189, 65, 119, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 24, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 9, 65, 115, 100, 102, 103, 104, 64]);
```

The problem is when I change the salt byte array to string, it will have different characters in it than in the .Net code. The two output is fairly similar, but sometimes there will be another replacement character in Node, and I don't know why.

Here are the two outputs again:

```js
const nodeJs = [239, 191, 189, 106, 6, 239, 191, 189, 111, 229, 165, 162, 239, 191, 189, 86, 239, 191, 189, 89, 239, 191, 189, 76, 94, 105, 239, 191, 189, 1, 50, 239, 191, 189, 65, 119, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 24, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 9, 65, 115, 100, 102, 103, 104, 64];
const dotNet = [239, 191, 189, 106, 6, 239, 191, 189, 111, 229, 165, 162, 239, 191, 189, 86, 239, 191, 189, 89, 239, 191, 189, 76, 94, 105, 239, 191, 189, 1, 50, 239, 191, 189, 65, 119, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 24, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 9, 65, 115, 100, 102, 103, 104, 64];
```

The `239, 191, 189` pattern is the replacement character (`xFFFD`) I guess that's supposed to be there when the byte sequence can't be translated using the encoding (or at least that's what I understood). But in the byte arrays around index 48 there is one extra replacement in the `nodeJs` array and then from index 58 the two arrays differ in more bytes as well.

**My main goal is to have the same result in NodeJs as in .NET and then I would really like to understand why is there a difference. Any help is appreciated!**

Here's the .NET code as well for reference:

```
byte[] bsalt = ...
UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
string p = encoding.GetString(bsalt) + pass;
byte[] pwdByteArray = encoding.GetBytes(p);
```